# T-Sql USE command: how to handle errors?

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, sql-server-2008-r2

I run a script which SELECTs data from several databases on the same server.

```
USE db1
SELECT x from tbl1
USE db2
SELECT y from tbl2
... etc.
```

If one of the databases is being restored from a backup, the script errors out on the USE statement.  How can I handle these errors?  TRY - CATCH doesn't work.

This is on 2008R2.

Edit: The error returned is:

```
Msg 927, Level 14, State 2, Line 4
Database 'db2' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.
```

Comment: Can you just skip the "USE" and use 3 part names? Can you try looking at sys.databases to see what state the database is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the current status of a database using `DATABASEPROPERTYEX`:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db_name', 'Status')
```

This will output the current status of your database, which will include whether it is restoring (which will give a status of '`RESTORING`').

Before executing your USE, do the following:

```
DECLARE @Status SQL_VARIANT
SELECT @Status = DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db1', 'Status')

IF (@Status = 'ONLINE')
BEGIN
    USE db1
    -- Do stuff
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Do other stuff
END
```